# MLE for distribution having most general form

Tags: estimation, maximum-likelihood

Consider a random sample {8,4,1/2,1} from a distribution having most general form of the probability mass function
f(x,Θ) = (x/Θ)^(Θ A'(Θ)) exp(A(Θ)+C(x))
where A'(Θ) is the derivative of A(Θ) with respect to Θ, The maximum likelihood estimator of Θ is?

I tried differentiating log-likelihood but was not able to solve it further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how you tried to differentiate the log-likelihood, but I tried to proceed in following way:

The pmf is given by,
$f(x_i;\theta)=(\frac{x_i}{\theta})^{\theta A'(\theta)}e^{A(\theta)+C(x_i)}$
The joint pmf for n number of sample is given by,
$f(\mathbf{x},\theta)=\prod_{i=1}^n(\frac{x_i}{\theta})^{\theta A'(\theta)}e^{A(\theta)+C(x_i)}
\Rightarrow (\frac{\prod_{i=1}^n x_i}{\theta^n})^{\theta A'(\theta)}e^{nA(\theta)}e^{\sum_{i=1}^n C(x_i)}$
The likelihood function will be given by,
$\\L(\theta;\mathbf{x})=(\frac{\prod_{i=1}^n x_i}{\theta^n})^{\theta A'(\theta)}e^{nA(\theta)}e^{\sum_{i=1}^n C(x_i)}$
The log-likelihhod will be given by,
$l(\theta)=\theta A'(\theta)\sum_{i=1}^n\log x_i-n\theta A'(\theta)\log \theta+nA(\theta)+\sum_{i=1}^n C(x_i)$ 
The next step is solve the following equation for $\theta$
$\frac{\mathbf{d}l(\theta)}{\mathbf{d}\theta}=0$
$\Rightarrow A'(\theta)\sum \log x_i+\theta A''(\theta)\sum \log x_i-nA'(\theta)\log \theta-n\theta A''(\theta)\log \theta-nA'(\theta)+nA'(\theta)=0$
$\Rightarrow A'(\theta)[\sum \log x_i-n\log \theta]+\theta A''(\theta)[\sum \log x_i-n\log \theta]=0$
$\Rightarrow (\sum \log x_i-n\log \theta)(A'(\theta)+\theta A''(\theta))=0$
Then, if we take
$[\sum \log x_i-n\log \theta]=0$
$\Rightarrow n\log \theta=\sum \log x_i$
$\log \theta=\frac{1}{n}\sum \log x_i$
$\hat{\theta}_{mle}=e^{\frac{1}{n}\sum \log x_i}$